# ng-Model is not updating from a nicEdit formatted Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, nicedit

```
<scirpt src="textarea.js"></script>
<script>
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
new nicEditor({maxHeight : 200}).panelInstance('area');
});
</script>

<p>
   <textarea name="area" id="area" style="height:200px;" 
             ng-model="text" wrap="true">
   </textarea>
</p>
<p id="comment-text">{{text}}</p>
```

Here i used a paragraph to review the text entered by the user, but the model is not showing any text entered !
when i remove the id attribute of textarea, it starts working.
Can anyone propose me a solution ?

Comment: Is this erro in your code? scirpt    =   <scirpt src="textarea.js"></script>

Comment: nicEdit throws away the original textarea element.  You'll need to hook into whatever event/dom interface nicEdit provides (which doesn't appear to be much).

Comment: If there isn't an angular module that wraps that editor into a directive available...you either need to create your own that will keep model updated or find another angular modularized editor

Comment: No, i have a script page where i placed some of my scripts. To that page i placed that link there. @Claudio Castro

Answer (score 0):

This is a little workaround, but should work for you. You can add event listener for `keyup`, which will update the textarea as you type (nicEditor by default only updates on form submit).  Also, you need to trigger `input` event in order for `ng-model` to update.

```
<script>
var areaEditor;
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    new nicEditor({maxHeight : 200}).panelInstance('area');

    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        nicEditors.findEditor('area').saveContent()
        var event = new Event('input', {});
        document.getElementById('area').dispatchEvent(event);
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: whats any other way to add a formatting textarea with the angular part working?

Comment: what issues you have with the code i posted? is the keyup event fired as you type?  Put a console.log() inside the handler

Comment: no, it isnt working at all. Instead the editor vanishes leaving the textarea as it is

Comment: any errors or anything? i got the above code working ok. Can you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: try this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/setg46qz/3/   You will need to work how to sanitize and display the resulting html with ng-bind-html , but you get the idea from this fiddle how to capture the output